# Input of Lambda in a Step Function after a DynamoDB get state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions

If I have a Step Function with the following architecture

Input -> Lambda 1 -> DynamoDB Get -> Lambda 2 -> End

then what would be the input of Lambda 2? Is it possible for Lambda 2 to receive as input both the output of Lambda 1 and the get of the DynamoDB state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different steps can store their results in different nodes of `ResultPath`, so step 1 can put its result into `$.foo`, step 2 under `$.bar` and step 3 will see get `{"foo": {...}, "bar": {...}}` as an input